# Form action on landing page

Tags: forms, action

I have a site(wordpress), and I received a pre-made landing page to upload to my site.
This landing page has a button which supposed to send the input that a user enters (name, last name) to a file named results.php
Right now the "search now" button does nothing.
I haven’t figured out how to make it work.
Please help,
Many thanks

this is the html/php page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
 <title>yoursite.com</title>
 <link href="img/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans+Narrow:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <link href="css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

<!-- Header -->
<header id="header">
 <div class="wrapper cf">
  <h1 class="site-logo"><a href="#"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="yoursite.com"></a></h1>
  <div class="arrested">
   <div class="arrested-title">.. Today:</div>
   <div class="arrested-list">
    <ul>
     <li><span><img src="img/mug.jpg" alt=""></span><span>John Smith</span></li>
     <li><span><img src="img/mug.jpg" alt=""></span><span>John Smith</span></li>
     <li><span><img src="img/mug.jpg" alt=""></span><span>John Smith</span></li>
     <li><span><img src="img/mug.jpg" alt=""></span><span>John Smith</span></li>
     <li><span><img src="img/mug.jpg" alt=""></span><span>John Smith</span></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
<!-- // Header -->

<!-- Content -->
<div id="main">
 <div class="wrapper cf">
  <div class="search-content cf">
   <div class="search-secure">All searches are Secure</div>
   <div class="search-header cf">
    <div class="search-header-content">
     <div class="search-header-content-inn">
      <h2 class="search-title"><span>yoursite.com</span>  Search Service</h2>
      <div class="search-database">Database Update on September 8, 2015</div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-header-sidebar">
     <div class="search-map"><img src="img/map.png" alt=""></div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="search-form cf">
    <div class="search-start"><span>Start Your Search Below</span></div>
    <div class="cell">
     <input id="firstname" type="text" name="firstname" value="" placeholder="FIRST NAME" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
     <input id="lastname" type="text" name="lastname" value="" placeholder="LAST NAME" />
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
     <select id="state" name="state"><option value="00">SELECT STATE</option><option value="ALL">Nationwide</option><option value="AL">AL</option><option value="AK">AK</option><option value="AR">AR</option><option value="AZ">AZ</option><option value="CA">CA</option><option value="CO">CO</option><option value="CT">CT</option><option value="DC">DC</option><option value="DE">DE</option><option value="FL">FL</option><option value="GA">GA</option><option value="HI">HI</option><option value="IA">IA</option><option value="ID">ID</option><option value="IL">IL</option><option value="IN">IN</option><option value="KS">KS</option><option value="KY">KY</option><option value="LA">LA</option><option value="MA">MA</option><option value="MD">MD</option><option value="ME">ME</option><option value="MI">MI</option><option value="MN">MN</option><option value="MO">MO</option><option value="MS">MS</option><option value="MT">MT</option><option value="NE">NE</option><option value="NH">NH</option><option value="NJ">NJ</option><option value="NM">NM</option><option value="NV">NV</option><option value="NC">NC</option><option value="ND">ND</option><option value="NY">NY</option><option value="OH">OH</option><option value="OK">OK</option><option value="OR">OR</option><option value="PA">PA</option><option value="RI">RI</option><option value="SD">SD</option><option value="SC">SC</option><option value="TN">TN</option><option value="TX">TX</option><option value="UT">UT</option><option value="VA">VA</option><option value="VT">VT</option><option value="WA">WA</option><option value="WI">WI</option><option value="WV">WV</option><option value="WY">WY</option></select>
    </div>
    <div class="cell btn">
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search Now" />
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="search-incs cf">
    <h3 class="search-title">Records on File:</h3>
    <div class="search-incs-list cf">
     <ul>
      
      <li>And More...</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="search-report"></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- // Content -->

<!-- Footer -->
<footer id="footer">
 <div class="wrapper cf">
  <div class="fnav cf">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Privacy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Terms</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="fcopy">
   <p>&copy; Copyright 2015 yoursite.com. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</footer>
<!-- // Footer -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have no `<form></form>` element. Semantically, a form without the outer wrapped `<form>` element is incorrect. Providing a class with `form` in it will not make the browser recognize the `<div>` as a form. The only way to make the above code work would be to use JavaScript and AJAX.

Comment: thats strange. it wasn't supposed to be that complex.